# Google Analytics site search configured but not showing any data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to configure site search analytics for my website. The site already gathers other analytics data, but I can't get any data to appear for search.

My site search URLs look like this:

`https://my.funsite.com/display/URSD/Search?run_1_component=daemon&run_1_sub_solution=%3CAny%3E&run_1_search_string=component%20statuses&run_1=run`

Where in the above:

`run_1_search_string` is the search string and `run_1_component` and `run_1_sub_solution` are parameters for refining the search.

In Google Analytics I have the following configuration:

[image: Site search configuration]

The thing is though, I'm not seeing any search data being gathered.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, or at least a way to fix it for me.

The tracking code was using the google analytics classic ga.js snippet. When I updated to use the new tracking code analytics.js (which is what the google analytics site gives me), it worked.

Another somewhat related thing - with my version of google analytics (the basic free version) I seem to only be able to specify one category parameter. It's a bit confusing because "Query Parameter" is singular but allows multiple parameters, but the same doesn't apply for categories.